# Integer multiplication without using multiply operator

Tags: java, bitwise

I wrote a method that multiplies two integers. Is there a faster approach that doesn't use the `*` operator?

The method `mult(a, b)` multiplies two arbitrary integers. Is there a quicker way to multiply two numbers, without using `*` in java?

```
static int mult(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b)
        return recMult(a, b);
    return recMult(b, a);
}

static int recMult(int max, int min) {
    if (min <= 1)
        return min == 1 ? max : 0;
    int cntOfMin = 0, i = 1;
    while ((i = i << 1) <= min)
        cntOfMin++;
    return (max << cntOfMin) + recMult(max, min - (1 << cntOfMin));
}
```

This method doesn't work on negative numbers and doesn't handle overflows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your heuristic is not optimal.  `recMult` is using binary arithmetic to multiply two numbers.  It recurses a number of times based on the number of 1-bits in the second number.  You pass in the smaller of the two numbers as the second number, but there is no guarantee the smaller number has fewer 1-bits.

Consider `8 * 7`, or in binary, `1000 * 111`.  The `7` is the smaller number, so you use it as the second argument, and you compute `(8 << 2) + (8 << 1) + (8 << 0) + 0`.  If you had chosen to `8` as the second argument, you would have computed `(7 << 3) + 0` ... far fewer operations.

The function [`Integer.bitCount(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int)) returns the number of 1-bits in an integer.  Using this, we could rewrite `mult(int a, int b)` as follows:

```
static int mult(int a, int b) {
    if (Integer.bitCount(a) > Integer.bitCount(b))
        return recMult(a, b);
    return recMult(b, a);
}
```

The result should be faster.

Similarly, Java provides several functions in the [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) class which can directly extract the 1-bits found in an integer.  These are `.lowestOneBit(i)`, `.highestOneBit(i)`, `.numberOfLeadingZeros(i)`, and `.numberOfTrailingZeros(i)`.  The last function is most useful here, as the number of trailing zeros corresponds to the bit position of the least significant 1-bit.  For example, `8`, or `1000` has 3 trailing zeros, and `(1 << 3) == 8`.

Using this to simplify `rectMult()`, we could get something like:

```
private static int recMult(int multiplicand, int multiplier) {
    int product = 0;
    while (multiplier != 0) {
        int shift = Integer.numberTrailingZeros(multiplier);
        product += multiplicand << shift;
        multiplier -= 1 << shift;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Since the second number is no longer guaranteed to be the smaller of the two, I've renamed `max` and `min` to `multiplicand` and `multiplier`.

I've also replaced the recursion with a simple loop, which should additionally speed things up.

Additionally, I've declared this helper function `private`, since it is unlikely other classes will use it.